# Why MDI Child not gaining focus after user returns from Form.ShowDialog()

Tags: c#, datagridview, mdi, showdialog, mdichild

I have a MDI child (FormA) form that opens and displays a `dataGridView`.

The user has the ability to make changes to a record in the database by opening another form (FormB) that is outside of the MDI. Meaning that it is called with `FormB.ShowDialog()` rather than `FormB.Show().`

FormA has an activated event that I want to be thrown when the user returns from FormB. I do this to refresh the datagridview's datasource.

It seems that FormA never loses focus and I need to in order for the activated event to be thrown when the user returns. Is this by design? How can I achieve this functionality?

**EDIT**

FormB is called from FormA's MDI Parent. not FormA itself.

Comment: I believe that because it is a `ShowDialog` call, the original form is not really losing focus per se.  Instead why don't you fire the event when the dialog returns?  `if (FormB.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { refreshTheDataSource(); }`

Comment: @EvanL I would do that if FormB was being called from FormA but its not. Its being called from the MDI Parent

Comment: An MDI child form's Activated event only runs when you switch from one child to another.  Something you'll have to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need `Activated` event at all? The `FormB.ShowDialog()` opens `FormB` in a modal state, so execution of the code in the calling form `FormA` is interrupted.
See the sample (to use in the `FormA`):

```
using (FormB frm = new FormB())
    if (frm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // here FormB is closed by user.
    }
```

**EDIT**
Since `FormB` is opened from the MDI parent, you can save the currently active form to variable and then pass the execution to it. Try this in the MDI parent form:

```
FormA saveForm = ActiveMdiChild as FormA;
using (FormB frm = new FormB())
    if (frm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (saveForm != null)
            saveForm.UpdateDataGridView();  // Call the method of a previously active form.
    }
```

*You can also try the `ActivateMdiChild` method to activate a child form.*

Comment: FormB isn't being called from FormA. Its being called from the MDI Parent

Comment: The `saveForm` *sees* only accessible members of the `FormA` class: having `public`, and maybe `internal`, `protected internal` access modifiers. So set `public` modifier for the desired methods.

Comment: There are a lot of ways I can use this. Thank you!!